# Share same component instance

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I need to use the same instance of a component into an aura:iteration to avoid to instance the same component different times because the component in the iteration need to have unique information. How can I achieve this?

Example:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.myObject}" var="obj">
    <!-- This component need to share same instance, not to instantiate multiple times -->
    <c:innerComponent myAttribute={!v.attr} />
</aura:iteration>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can send the same attribute value to each of the component inside the iteration.

Comment: I try to explain better: I have several tabs based on different product categories; I generate that tabs via aura:iteration and I need to put my inner component (that is a filter-tool component) inside of every of the tabs that I generate at runtime, but I don't want to instatiate it multiple times because it need to have the same informations even when i switch tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** use same instance of a component the time you use it multiple times in [component composition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_composition.htm).

Components work similar as a class/instance notion of any Object Oriented Programming. When you write a component in a *.cmp* file, you are necessarily *defining* the component. And the time you utilize your *.cmp* in a tag on any other component, you are creating an *instance* of that component.

So if you use a component within an iteration, you will end up creating different instances of the component and that there's no way you can always deal with the same instance there.

Refer to the below excerpt from the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_composition.htm).

> In object-oriented programming, there’s a difference between a class and an instance of that class. Components have a similar concept. When you create a .cmp resource, you are providing the definition (class) of that component. When you put a component tag in a .cmp , you are creating a reference to (instance of) that component.

Comment: what if I want to share some informations between different same component instances? i.e.: I have a component that allow you to select some filters and I have 3 instances of that component for every product category tab, but filters are shared between all 3 products category and I need to have it on every tab (I can't instatiate the filter component only one time, but I have to instantiate it for every aura:iteration and at the same time I need to share the selected filters between all 3 filters components)

Comment: That's when you use the attributes. If you know that in every scenario one of the attributes will always be "same", you just pass the value from parent component on the child component. You don't need to depend for that value based on your iteration.